# Add FileVersion to MSI

Tags: winapi, wix, windows-installer

I would like to add a FileVersion to a .MSI file.
I do **not want** to add a Version for the installed product/files. I'm looking for a way to modify the MSI, so I can add something like a .RC header (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(VS.85).aspx).
It has to remain MSI, I can not change it to an executable.

I can work with... WinAPI? .NET? WiX? ... any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "FileVersion" for a MSI file. There is only a MSI PorductVersion.

The [ProductVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx) is normal property in an MSI file.

In WiX you find the `ProductVersion` directly in the project node ([see WiX docu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545666/wix-read-productname-and-productversion-from-msi)).

You can retrieve the information with MSI-Api or COM accessing the properties table. Here a [C# sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347325/checking-productversion-of-an-msi-programatically).

Comment: Not exactly what I asked for, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347325/checking-productversion-of-an-msi-programatically does the trick as well. Thanks!